# For/While cycle with double condition in excel

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I have a list with date intervals and currency conversions associated to those intervals. See example below:

```
Start Date  Close Date  EUR
30/03/2013  26/04/2013  1.18
30/03/2013  26/04/2013  1.18
27/04/2013  24/05/2013  1.19
25/05/2013  28/06/2013  1.17
29/06/2013  26/07/2013  1.17
27/07/2013  23/08/2013  1.16
24/08/2013  27/09/2013  1.16 
28/09/2013  25/10/2013  1.19
26/10/2013  22/11/2013  1.17
23/11/2013  27/12/2013  1.2
28/12/2013  24/01/2014  1.2
05/01/2014  21/02/2014  1.21
22/02/2014  28/03/2014  1.21
29/03/2014  25/04/2014  1.21
26/04/2014  23/05/2014  1.21
04/05/2014  27/06/2014  1.24
08/06/2014  25/07/2014  1.25
26/07/2014  22/08/2014  1.26
23/08/2014  25/09/2014  1.25
26/09/2014  23/10/2014  1.28
```

I need to convert each date interval into single lines including all possible dates within the interval, and keep the respective conversion rates. So for the first date interval it would be:

```
30/03/2013  1.18
31/03/2013  1.18
01/04/2013  1.18
02/04/2013  1.18
03/04/2013  1.18
04/04/2013  1.18
05/04/2013  1.18
06/04/2013  1.18
07/04/2013  1.18
08/04/2013  1.18
09/04/2013  1.18
10/04/2013  1.18
11/04/2013  1.18
12/04/2013  1.18
13/04/2013  1.18
14/04/2013  1.18
15/04/2013  1.18
16/04/2013  1.18
17/04/2013  1.18
18/04/2013  1.18
19/04/2013  1.18
20/04/2013  1.18
21/04/2013  1.18
22/04/2013  1.18
23/04/2013  1.18
24/04/2013  1.18
25/04/2013  1.18
26/04/2013  1.18
```

Is there anyway to this easily for all date ranges? I've come up with something like this in excel:

`=IF(AND(A1>='Sheet1'!$A$1, A1<='Sheet1'!$B$1), 'Sheet1'!$C$1)`, A1=current cell containing a date; Sheet1!A1=Start Date; Sheet1!B1=Close Date; C1=EUR conversion

The problem is that I need it to move to the following row everytime the conditions don't apply. Meaning, everytime the date being analysed is outside the interval in question, I need to increase the row position by one in Sheet1. Any help would be appreciated. VBA would be fine.

Best,
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateAllInfo()

    Dim inputArr()
    inputArr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C21").Value 'Exludes header

    Dim i As Long, y As Long, rowCounter As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = LBound(inputArr, 1) To UBound(inputArr, 1)
        For y = inputArr(i, 1) To inputArr(i, 2)
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                .Cells(rowCounter, 1) = y
                .Cells(rowCounter, 2) = inputArr(i, 3)
            End With
        Next y
    Next i
    ActiveSheet Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

That is in case number of dates is too large for Transpose to handle otherwise can do whole thing with an array and write direct to sheet:

```
 Option Explicit

Sub GenerateAllInfo()

    Dim inputArr()
    inputArr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:C21").Value 'Exludes header. 
    Dim outputArr
    ReDim outputArr(1 To 2000, 1 To 2)

    Dim i As Long, y As Long, rowCounter As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = LBound(inputArr, 1) To UBound(inputArr, 1)
        For y = inputArr(i, 1) To inputArr(i, 2)
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
            outputArr(rowCounter, 1) = y
            outputArr(rowCounter, 2) = inputArr(i, 3)
        Next y
    Next i

    outputArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArr)

    ReDim Preserve outputArr(1 To 2, 1 To rowCounter)
    outputArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArr)

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1), UBound(outputArr, 2)).Value = outputArr
        .Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi QHarr,

It might be, don't know enough of VBA anymore :P It has been too long. I see the double For cycle so it mught something like that. 

I've added the code to sheet1, changed the date format to "dd/mm/yyyy" but can't find out out to activate and fill in sheet2. Should it create another sheet automatically and fill in with the values?

Comment: I chose it to add a new sheet and fill it there. Where in sheet 2 do you want it to go?

Comment: The code goes in a standard module not in sheet code pane.I have updated both version as per your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Small Change in both the code.

ActiveSheet Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

to

**ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"**

Comment: This should be a comment on the answer of QHarr.

Comment: I've tried both with the correction but can't get the values filled in. Should I expect that when I add another sheet the values would be filled in in column A?

Comment: My apologies i couldn't comment due to lack of reputation. I will refrain from making changes until I have the necessary reputation. Regards.

Comment: @antoniogouveia the code will create a new sheet on its own and fill in the values. Make sure your pasting the code in a module

Comment: One more thing, if I now want to apply that code to the my entire dataset what changes do I need to make? I have 68 rows and 5 columns with different currency conversions for the different 68 date ranges.

Comment: share a sample dataset it would help.

Comment: Can't fit the entire dataset here but I've done it manually for the different columns with the piece of code I got from you. Thank you all for your help!